# How to convert SFZ synthesizer format to (soundfont) SF2?

Tags: soundfont

I have created a `sfz` file and compiled a corresponding file-tree of instrument samples.

Is there software that convert this `sfz` filetree to a `sf2` soundfont file?

The reason is: I can easily create the `sfz` file-tree, and easily use the `sf2` file. However, creating the `sf2` requires special software and playing the `sfz` does not appear to be supported by `timidity`.

Comment: For future searchers, here's a lead: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/33145/convert-sfz-to-sf2-soundfonts-via-command-line.  If I find anything else more substantial I'll write up an answer

Answer (score 2):

Here are two different utilities you can use to convert an sfz file and file-tree to an sf2 file.

1. Use [`polyphone`](https://polyphone-soundfonts.com) with the following command: `polyphone -1 -i your-soundfont.sfz`
2. Use [`convertSoundBank.py` from freepats-tools](https://github.com/freepats/freepats-tools): `convertSoundBank.py grandPiano.sfz grandPiano.sf2`